# Call to a member function fill() on null

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to do an update keeping the following information:

```
$radicado = \App\Radicado::find($id);
        $radicado->fill($request->all());
        $radicado->codigoRadicado = $request['codigoRadicado'];
        $radicado->Dependencia_idDependencia = $request['Dependencia_idDependencia'];
        $radicado->Serie_idSerie = $request['Serie_idSerie'];
        $radicado->SubSerie_idSubSerie = $request['SubSerie_idSubSerie'];
        $radicado->save();
        if($request->ajax())
    {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Actualizado correctamente']);
    }

    return redirect('/radicado');
```

and for this run the following ajax

```
var token = document.getElementById('token').value;
    $.ajax({
        async: true,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token},
        url: $(formId).attr('action'),
        type: $(formId).attr('method'),
        data: $(formId).serialize(),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result){
            $(formId)[0].reset();
            alert(result);
            document.getElementById("preview").style.display = "none";
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('No se ha actualizado el documento.');
        }
    });
```

But when I get this error store: Call to a member function fill() on null

Comment: what are you getting when you `dd($radicado)` ?

Comment: this means that `\App\Radicado::find($id);` return `null` value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines shown are this:

```
$radicado = \App\Radicado::find($id);
$radicado->fill($request->all());
```

The error is because your `find()` statement did not find a record with that `$id`. Since it did not find a record, it returns `null`. Since it returns `null`, `$radicado` is now `null`, and you cannot call methods on a `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that the row exists. Try `firstOrFail()`

```
$radicado = \App\Radicado::firstOrFail($id);
```

If its still not working, double check your facade or model.